# Parallel factorial with multiple threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing, factorial

I'm trying to make a function that calculates factorial of a number in parallel, just for testing purposes. 
Let's say I have 4 cores on my cpu, so I will split the "problem" in 4 chunks.

Saying that, I made this:

```
public class FactorialPTest
{
    public static object _locker = new object();

    public static long Factorial(int x)
    {
        long result = 1;
        int right = 0;
        int nr = x;
        bool done = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < nr; i += (nr / 4))
        {
            int step = i;

            new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
                {
                    right = (step + nr / 4) > nr ? nr : (step + nr / 4);
                    long chunkResult = ChunkFactorial(step + 1, right);

                    lock (_locker)
                    {
                        result *= chunkResult;
                        if (right == nr)
                            done = true;
                    }
                })).Start();
        }

        while(!done)
        { 
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static long ChunkFactorial(int left, int right)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("left: {0} ; right: {1}", left, right);
        Console.WriteLine("ChunkFactorial Thread ID :" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        if (left == right)
            return left == 0 ? 1 : left;
        else return right * ChunkFactorial(left, right - 1);
    }

    public static void main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Factorial(15));
    }
}
```

Sometimes is working, sometimes it gives me intermediary results and sometimes a deadlock happens.

Why is this happening? Shouldn't `Thread.Sleep(10)` pause the main thread until I get the final result ?

Comment: Well for starters, what if one thread sets done to true before the others have completed?

Comment: Try proper thread-sync by e.g. a Semaphore and wait for all threads to end.

Comment: @RagtimeWilly That's why I put that section in a lock block, so that a single thread at a time could make the multiplication of partial results. Just the last one is supposed to set done to true ( by checking if right is equal to the factorial being calculated.

Comment: @darkdante - but the "last one" *could* finish before one of the others.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks, I missed that:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest looking into the [Task Parallel Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Among other things it will abstract away a lot of the low concerns relating to multi-threading.

You can represent each chunk of work with a task, add to a collection and then wait for them all to finish:

```
public static long Factorial(int x)
{
    long result = 1;
    int right = 0;
    int nr = x;
    bool done = false;

    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    for (int i = 0; i < nr; i += (nr / 4))
    {
        int step = i;
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
            {
                right = (step + nr / 4) > nr ? nr : (step + nr / 4);
                long chunkResult = ChunkFactorial(step + 1, right);

                lock (_locker)
                {
                    result *= chunkResult;
                }
            }));
    }

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

    return result;
}
```

In your original code the last chunk could conceivably complete it's work first and `right` would equal `nr` even though the other chunks hadn't been calculated. Also, `right` was getting shared between all the threads so this could also lead to some unpredictable results, i.e, all threads are trying to use this variable to hold different values at the same time.

Generally you should try to avoid sharing state between threads if possible. The code above could be improved by having each task return it's result and then use these results to calculate the final one:

```
public static long Factorial(int x)
{
    int nr = x;

    var tasks = new List<Task<long>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < nr; i += (nr / 4))
    {
        int step = i;
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
            {
                int right = (step + nr / 4) > nr ? nr : (step + nr / 4);
                return ChunkFactorial(step + 1, right);
            }));
    }

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

    return tasks.Select(t => t.Result).Aggregate(((i, next) => i * next));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use one of the `Parallel.For` overloads with aggregation, it will handle parallelism, partitioning of the workload and aggregation of the results for you. For `long` type of result, you can only do factorial of 21, if I am not mistaken. It also makes sense to add `checked {...}` to catch overflows. The code could looks like:

```
    public long CalculateFactorial(long value)
    {
        var result = 1L;
        var syncRoot = new object();
        checked
        {
            Parallel.For(
                // always 1
                1L,
                // target value
                value,
                // if need more control, add { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4}
                new ParallelOptions(),
                // thread local result init
                () => 1L,
                // next value
                (i, state, localState) => localState * i,
                // aggregate local thread results
                localState =>
                {
                    lock (syncRoot)
                    {
                        result *= localState;
                    }
                }
                );                
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Hope this helps.